# Can't match alphanumerics in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, coffeescript

I want to match a word with between 5 and 15 alphanumeric characters, and I may also include _ and - characters. I'm using JQuery to get the value of an input, I'm programming in CoffeeScript:

```
username = $('#register input[name="user"]').val()
if ( ! username.match('/^([\w_\-]{5,15})$/'))
    alert(username)
```

Which compiled in JS is this:

```
username = $('#register input[name="user"]').val();
if (!username.match('/^([\w_\-]{5,15})$/')) {
     return alert(username);
}
```

I get alerts with strings like "dsdsfsdsf" which should return true, in fact every string returns false when trying to match. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
if ( ! username.match('/^([\w_\-]{5,15})$/'))
```

to

```
if ( ! username.match(/^([\w_\-]{5,15})$/))
```

Regex literals must not be between quotes.

As you want to simply test your string, you'd better use the faster [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) and you don't need a capturing group :

```
if (!/^[\w_\-]{5,15}$/.test(username))
```